# Symfony2: How to render datetime-local fields with FormBuilder?

Tags: html, forms, symfony

The title says it all: How can i render html5 datetime-local fields from the formbuilder?
With

```
$builder->add('start', 'datetime', array('widget' => 'single_text'))
```

i can get a datetime field, but this is not supported by chrome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but for anybody coming across this post searching for a solution to that issue (like me), here is how I solved it:

Add a custom field type that inherits DateTimeType:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class LocalDateTimeType extends AbstractType
{
    const HTML5_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm";

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['widget'] = $options['widget'];

        if ($options['html5'] && 'single_text' === $options['widget'] && self::HTML5_FORMAT === $options['format']) {
            $view->vars['type'] = 'datetime-local';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'format' => self::HTML5_FORMAT
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'datetime';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'local_datetime';
    }
}
```

Register it as a service:

```
app.form.type.local_datetime:
    class: AppBundle\Form\Type\LocalDateTimeType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: local_datetime }
```

Now you may use it in your forms:

```
(...)
$builder->add('myLocalDateTimeField', 'local_datetime', [
    'widget' => 'single_text'
];
(...)
```

It's important that you set the widget to `single_text` - and yes, this is of course possible (as of Symfony 2.7).

Using localized dateTimes, you'll probably want to store your datetimes normalized in the database. A nice approach can be found here:

http://jeremycook.ca/2012/06/24/normalising-datetimes-with-doctrine-events/

Comment: This answer should be the marked as correct, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The widget 'single_text' is not supported by the [datetime field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html).

The date and time parts have independent widgets. For Example:

```
<?php
// from date
        $builder->add('DateFrom', 'datetime', array(
            'input'  => 'datetime',
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            'time_widget' => 'single_text',
            'empty_value' => '',
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            'label' => 'From Date',
            'required' => false,
            'mapped' => false
        ));
```

[Definition of the widget options for the date type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html).
[Definition of the widget options for the time type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/time.html).